# LocationMatch rules with Apache

Tags: regex, apache, locationmatch

I need to fix (with or without regex) so you can access "/admin.php?+" but not "/SUBSITE/admin.php?+" on a site. Anyone has a good idea of how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a regex which *might* fit your need (your original question was a bit vague):

```
^(?!www\.mysite\.com\/.*\/admin\.php).*$
```

I have tested this regex and it blocks `"www.mysite.com/*/admin.php"`, but it allows the following:

```
www.mysite.com/*/guestbook.php
www.mysite.com/*.php
```

If you want additional restrictions in the regex, then let me know and I can refine this answer.

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/iV0gK8/4)

Comment: I understand what you mean now when i read it. But basically what i meant is that you should be able to go to "www.mysite.com/admin.php?test=1" but not "www.mysite.com/SUBSITE/admin.php?test=1". With or without the querystring in the URL. And also SUBSITE can be anything, so its not just that path i want to restrict access to.

Comment: Please clarify your original question as it is not clear.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer @tim-biegeleisen, but SUBSITE can be anything. So it can be "www.mysite.com/apache/" or "www.mysite.com/test/".

Comment: If you will allow `SUBSITE` to be _anything_, then there would be no way to distinguish it from the case you want to match.  Again, you need to rethink your question.

Comment: What i want to do is to restrict access to "www.mysite.com/*/admin.php". I think that will be easier to understand :)

Comment: Can you give a few more examples of permissible and forbidden URLs?

Comment: You should be able to go to any other part of the site, so i guess i just need the restriction regex for "www.mysite.com/*/admin.php".

Comment: Can you please give a couple more allowed URLs?

Comment: Any other URL should be allowed, its just "www.mysite.com/*/admin.php" that should be restricted. So if i go to "www.mysite.com/*/guestbook.php" it should be possible. Should also be possible to access anything on the mainsite, like "www.mysite.com/*.php"

Comment: Looks great! what about if i want the "www.mysite.com" to be "*"? and just make it to be "*.se" instead?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Again, could you give me an example?

Comment: If i dont want it to be just for a specific site like "www.mysite.com". I want it to to be for any site so i can use the same regex on multiple sites. But i still want it to be restricted to the ".se" domain. So it should be like "*.se" instead, so i can use it on "www.test.se" and "www.site.se" but not on "www.test.com" and "www.site.com".

Comment: Then you can tweak the regex I gave you.  I will stop at this point.

Comment: It works like a charm! Thanks for all your work on this Tim Biegeleisen!

Comment: This is strange, when i tried to put "^(?!.se\/.*\/wp-admin\.php).*$" into the LocationMatch every single page was restricted on the website.

Comment: Are you restricting on matching this regex or not matching?